# Swift String init ambiguous(which String.init method does this code call?)

Tags: string, swift, initializer

It's a leetcode problem: 168. Excel Sheet Column Title @
https://leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-title/

---

The code works fine at my mac, 
but got compile error at leetcode:
**Line 5: ambiguous use of 'init'**
So, please tell me which String.init method does this code call?

```
String(UnicodeScalar(val))
```

And how I can solve this issue?

```
class Solution {
    func convertToTitle(n: Int) -> String {
        var alphabet = [String]()
        var result = ""
        alphabet = (UnicodeScalar("A").value...UnicodeScalar("Z").value).map({(val: UInt32) -> String in return String(UnicodeScalar(val)); })
        var num = n
        while num != 0 {
            num -= 1
            result = alphabet[num % 26] + result
            num /= 26
        }
        return result
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles in the latest Xcode, so I assume it's an issue with leetcode's compiler.

I believe the initializer that's supposed to get called here is [`init<T>(_: T)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/String/s:FSScurFMSSFq_SS). I don't know what other initializer their compiler is finding.

As for how to fix it, you could try something like `String(UnicodeScalar(val) as CustomStringConvertible)`.

Comment: sorry,still got the same compile error,I wrote a letter to leetcode, they said they uses the latest swift compiler from github.So best practice still not found.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles for me under linux on 2.2.1 and 3.0 Preview 1, but I ran across a similar problem in calling the UnicodeScalar constructor with single-character strings (`UnicodeScalar("A")`). Instead, try assigning the string values directly to `UnicodeScalar`-typed variables:

```
let a : UnicodeScalar = "A"
let z : UnicodeScalar = "Z"
let alphabet = (UnicodeScalar("A").value...UnicodeScalar("Z").value).map({(val: UInt32) -> String in return String(UnicodeScalar(val)); })
```